# Scrape info from a span title

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml

My html looks like this:

```
    <h3>Current Guide Price <span title="92">   92
    </span></h3>
```

The info I am trying to get is the 92.

here is another html page where i need to get the same data:

```
    <h3>Current Guide Price <span title="4,161">    4,161
    </span></h3>
```

I would need to get the 4,161 from this page.

here is the link to the page for reference:
http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/viewitem?obj=1613

What I have tried:

/h3/span[@title="92"]@title

/h3/span[@title="92"]/text()

/div[@class="stats"]/h3/span[@title="4,161"]@title

since the info I need is in the actual span tag, it is hard to grab the data in a dynamic way that I can use for many different pages.

Comment: Is the value of the `title` attribute inside the `span` tag always the same as the text value of `<h3>` tag?

Comment: @JackFleeting Yes.

Comment: So if you know which attribute value to use in the xpath expression, you also know the text in the `<h3>` tag; so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JackFleeting I don't know either of those things. The only thing i know is that it is always prepended with the text "Current Guide Price"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from lxml import html
import requests


baseUrl = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/viewitem?obj=2355'
page = requests.get(baseUrl)

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
price = tree.xpath('//h3/span')
price2 = tree.xpath('//h3/span/@title')
for p in price:
    print(p.text.strip())
for p2 in price2:
    print(p2)
```

The output is `92` in both cases.

Comment: I am getting invalid expression errors for both. Here is a code share. https://onlinegdb.com/By51mW74H

Comment: @Purin - I forgot lxml doesn't support `normalize-text()`; see edited answer.